# "Multiline comments" in VSCode v1.67 [resolved: pull request comments]

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the release notes in `VSCode April 2022 (version 1.67)`:

> ##### Multiline comments
>
> Behind the scenes, VS Code has supported multiline comments since the
> comments UX was finalized, but multiline comments were never surfaced
> in the UI. You can now see and leave multiline comments.

I notice that there is a new feature called `Multiline comments`.

However the description is not very explicit.

What is it used for and how to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be more general uses in the future for these "Comments" but primarily they are for commenting on pull requests.

So you have to have the [Github Pull Requests and Issues](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github) extension installed.  Which allows you to view pull requests within vscode itself.

When viewing a PR, you can create comments in the code like you can on github itself.  That is what the gif you linked to shows.  Adding a comment to a pull request.  There is no setting to enable the add a comment button, it is already there if the code is "commentable" - which I assume means it is part of the PR.

> Update: It looks like v1.69 will have a command to toggle these "comments" indicators on/off: `Comments: Toggle Editor Commenting`.

> v1.74 has added the ability to turn off this kind of "comments".
>
> The new setting `comments.visible` can be used to turn off editor
> commenting (the comments bar and the in-editor comments peek view).
> The command `Comments: Toggle Editor Commenting` can still be used to
> toggle editor commenting on and off during a session. Selecting a
> comment in the Comments view will always toggle commenting on.

If you have the Github Pull Request and Issues extension installed, there is a view in `View/Open View.../Pull Requests` you can open to see any pull requests.

Also, a `Comments` section will be added to the Panel showing any comments created in the workspace.

A brief demo:

[image: Pull Request Comments]

Comment: Of interest, for VSCode 1.71: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115808

Comment: And possibly https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150958