# Comment selection not happening in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to comment the selected text in VS Code and have tried the configured keyboard setting i.e. "Ctrl+K Ctrl+Alt+C". However everytime , I try it I get the below error
"The cursor must be within a commenting range to add a comment".

Can anyone tell me  what am  doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl+/`

Comment: what command is that keyboard chord (Ctrl+K Ctrl+Alt+C) bound to? I don't have such a binding on Ubuntu. Did it come from an extension? When I use `ctrl+shift+a` to toggle a block comment, that works just fine.

Comment: so are you trying to toggle whether the _code_ is commented out or not? Or are you trying to add an out-of-line comment to the code like the type from the GitHub PR extension?

Answer (score 0):

That particular command `Comments: Add Comment on Current Selection` is just for comments on github pull requests.  See more here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72356811 and https://dev.to/this-is-learning/code-review-on-a-github-pull-request-from-visual-studio-code-328l.

It is a little unfortunate that "comment" is used in the Keyboard Shortcuts to refer to both regular code comments and PR comments, but there you have it...

For the most common Windows shortcuts see [Keyboard Shortcuts: Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf).